# SQL Case Statement To Increment Value on THEN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written this CASE statement that checks for characters in a column ('Like' function). If characters are present then a 0 is stored in the UniqueStudentID column and if characters are not present then it does the 'Substring' calculation and stores that in the UniqueStudentID Column.

```
CASE WHEN RTRIM(S.STUD_Student_ID) LIKE '%ANON%' THEN 0 
     ELSE CAST((RTRIM(S.STUD_Student_ID) + RTRIM(SUBSTRING(AY.ACADYR_Academic_Year_Code,3,2) + SUBSTRING(AY.ACADYR_Academic_Year_Code,8,2))) AS bigint) 
END AS UniqueStudentID
```

My question is how would I change the query above so that the 0 after the THEN clause is incremental. So the first field that satisfies the LIKE condition is 0 then the next 1 then the next 2 and so on and anything that doesn't will use the ELSE condition code.

Would I be on the right lines to declare a counter and then use some sort of while or if statement. I have tried doing it but think im querying it incorrectly.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want `row_number()`?

```
CASE WHEN RTRIM(S.STUD_Student_ID) LIKE '%ANON%'
     THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN RTRIM(S.STUD_Student_ID) LIKE '%ANON%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
     ELSE . . .
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, so not row_number(). I would like if in the table STUD_Student_ID there is a field with that is LIKE %ANON% then store 0 in the a corresponding column called 'UniqueStudentID'. The problem is there are 3 fields in the table that satisify the %ANON% Characters so I don't want all to store as 0 (due to duplication). is there a way to increment it, so 0 then 1 then 2...so on if the data ever gets more than 3

Comment: Your latest edit worked like a charm! Thank you! And just for future references if there were more ANON fields...do I just keep going ELSE 2 END...but would be ELSE 3...?

Comment: @Daisy . . . I don't understand your last comment.  Perhaps you should ask a new question, with a clear explanation, sample data and desired results.